# Alert popping up multiple times and submit button only working after second click

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html

I am working on my CS50 Final Project. I am designing a web app:
I am using flask.
This happens in the login/register page. 
I am trying to check if the username is already taken( through jsonify) and if the password and the password confirmation are equal using JS.

So basically the problem is:
After loading tha page and filling out the register form nothing happens on the first click on the submit button. On the second click everything works just as it is supposed to: the functions run fine and check for matching passwords and if the username is available and alert if necessary. If I then close the alert window and click the submit button again I get two alerts from the usercheck function.
If do the same thing again 3 alerts then 4 and so on....For some reason the function gets called again and again but I can't figure out where....

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id='register' action='/register' method="POST"  onsubmit="return !!(passwordcheck() & usercheck());" ></form>
```

Here's the two JS function in a script tag in the same page:

```
 function passwordcheck(){

       const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
       const passwordc = document.getElementById('passwordc').value;

       if (password != passwordc){
         alert('Passwords do not match')
         return false;
       }
     }

        function usercheck(){

  $('document').ready(function(){

    $('form').on('submit',function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
      $.get('/check?username=' + username, function(r){
        if(r == false){
          alert('User taken');
          $('#username').focus();
        }
        else{
          (document).getElementById('register').submit();
        }
      } )
    })
  })
}
```

And  here's the  Python code from the application.py file that querys the database for the username:

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
    print(Fore.BLUE + "check function, line 99") 
    """Return true if username available, else false, in JSON format"""
    username = (request.args.get('username'),)
    if username:

        c.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =?", username)
        old_user = c.fetchall()

        if len(old_user) > 0:
            return jsonify(False)
        else:
            return jsonify(True)
```

Comment: Why have you placed the `jQuery` DOM ready function inside of your `usercheck()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined two handlers for the form submit event:
 - the first in the html (`onsubmit="return !!(passwordcheck() & usercheck());"`) is the `userCheck` function that does not actually make a request
 - the second inside the `userCheck` function (`$('form').on('submit',function(e){`) that does make a request

So the first time you submit the `userCheck` function is called, it does not make a request but add a submit event handler to the form. That is why the request is made only after submitting the form a second time.

You should be better off with something like this:

```
function passwordcheck() {

    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    const passwordc = document.getElementById('passwordc').value;

    if (password != passwordc) {
        alert('Passwords do not match')
        return false;
    }
}

function usercheck(handleSuccess, handleError) {
    var username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
    $.get('/check?username=' + username, function(r) {
        if (r == false) {
            handleError();
        } else {
            handleSuccess();
        }
    })
}

function submit() {
    (document).getElementById('register').submit();
}

function handleUserError () {
    alert('User taken');
    $('#username').focus();
}

$('document').ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!passwordcheck()) {
            return;
        }

        usercheck(submit, handleUserError);
    })
})
```

and without the `onsubmit` attribute on your form element.